# How can I catch error when can't create DB

Tags: sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite, cordova-plugins

I use cordovaSQLite plugin for cordova app. When I open a db like

```
db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("MCApp/.db", 0);
```

The db can't be created, becouse of de slash, so it will throw a error.

My question now, how can I catch this error for logging? there is no catch funciton etc.

regards

Comment: you could use and if statement within the sql create, then have another query log it to a logging table if it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only Cordova I usually do it like this

```
db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: "my.db", location: 2 }, successcb, errorcb);
```

This way you can define your success and error callbacks.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Great!